# Radio buttons not showing error text message

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I'm setting an error to the radio buttons, but while showing error they are only showing the red icon but not the text message.

How can I show a text message below the radio button?

Please help me!

**xml file**

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/radioLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_input_layout_address">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/radio_header"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large"/>

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_16dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioTwoWheeler"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:text="@string/radio_two_wheeler"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_middle" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioFourWheeler"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:text="@string/radio_four_wheeler"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_middle" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>
```

**java code**

```
RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(radioGroup.getChildCount()-1);
        radioButton.setError(getString(R.string.msg_uncheck_radio_button));
```

Comment: do you have the string set up correctly in the strings.xml file?

Comment: Yes, It is correct.